# How to fix "bad source file: ./Convert.java file does not contain class Converter

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a project where I am messing around with GUIs for the first time.  I am running into issues with the following errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hhsC.png)

I'm not quite sure why it's not able to communicate with the other files.

I've tried different compilers and tried to include the "package GuiConverter" on the GuiConverter.java line as well but it produces other errors when I do that

```
package GuiConverter;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

class Converter
{
    private double input;
    public Converter() 
    {
        input = Double.NaN;
    }
    public Converter(double input)
    
    
    {
        this.input = input;
    }
    double get()
    {
        return input;
    }
    void set(double input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }
    double convert()
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

---

```
package GuiConverter;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

class TemperatureConverter extends Converter
{
    public TemperatureConverter(double input)
    {
        super(input);
    }
    @Override
    double convert()
    {
        if(super.get() == Double.NaN)
            return Double.NaN;
        double answer = ((super.get() - 32) * 5) / 9;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

---

```
package GuiConverter;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

class DistanceConverter extends Converter
{
    public DistanceConverter(double input)
    {
        super(input);
    }
    @Override
    double convert()
    {
        if(super.get() == Double.NaN)
            return Double.NaN;
        double answer = super.get() * 1.609;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class GuiConverter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Converter");
        JButton distance = new JButton("Distance converter");
        JButton temperature = new JButton("Temperature converter");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(distance, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(temperature, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(exit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        
        distance.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Input miles distance to convert.");
                Converter c = new DistanceConverter(Double.parseDouble(input));
                double result = c.convert();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, input + " miles is equals to " + result + " km.");
            }
        });
        
        temperature.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Input fahrenheit temperature to convert.");
                Converter c = new TemperatureConverter(Double.parseDouble(input));
                double result = c.convert();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, input + " F is equals to " + result + " C");
            }
        });
        
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `.java` files are not executable or "source files" as the error says. You need to compile them to `.class` files... Please show your CLI command you use to run this

Comment: `GuiConverter` class in the same package or different?

Comment: your using GuiConverter as class name as well as package name is confusing. Change the package to something like **converters** overall and import it at the top of your GuiConverter class, that should solve the issue

Comment: If you are using some IDE like Eclipse, then its fine to use .Java files. However, each class should be exists in a separate file

Comment: As the others have said, your package name shouldn't really be the same as one of your classes. It should also be lower case. I wouldn't use the default (no) package either but would put `GuiConverter` in package `gui`. Otherwise @alainlompo has it right

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three problems.

1. Java naming convention of packages is lowercase. Please change package name GuiConverter to guiconverter.
2. The directories with source files have to reflect the package structure. Please move all files but the GuiConverter.java to the subdirectory guiconverter.
3. Another error says "cannot access Converter". It is because the Converter class is in another package then the GuiConverter class.

Please add public modifier to all your classes definitions.

For example:

```
public class Converter {...}
```

instead of:

```
class Converter {...}
```